# Using Shift key Multi selection of checkbox( Find Controls within 2 points/ rectangle

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, checkbox, multi-select

In order to select multiple checkbox within Wrap panel using Shift Key.

Capturing the Mouse down event position on Shift Keydown, on second mouse down with shift keydown, getting the 2 positions of the selection, then Need to Select the checkbox control with in the selected area.

How do I find the controls within 2 positions (System.Window.Point) or System.Windows.rect. The following code is selecting all of the checkbox within the wrappanel(lesscolorpanel).

```
 private System.Windows.Point startPoint;
    System.Windows.Point checkpPoint;
    private System.Windows.Point PointWhereMouseIs;
    private void LessColourPanel_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
        {
            if (startPoint == checkpPoint)
            {
                //GET THE MOUSE POSITION
                startPoint = Mouse.GetPosition(lessColourPanel);
                PointWhereMouseIs = checkpPoint;
            }
            else if(PointWhereMouseIs==checkpPoint)
            {
                //CAPTURE END MOUSE POSITION 
                PointWhereMouseIs = Mouse.GetPosition(lessColourPanel);
                //FIND CONTROLS WIHIN RECTANGLE
                Rect selareaRect = new Rect(startPoint, PointWhereMouseIs);
                foreach (System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox chkitemBox in FindVisualChildren<System.Windows.Controls.CheckBox>(lessColourPanel))
                {
                    var rectBounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(chkitemBox);
                    Vector vector = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(chkitemBox);
                    rectBounds.Offset(vector);
                    if (rectBounds.IntersectsWith(selareaRect))
                    {
                        chkitemBox.IsChecked = true;
                    }
                }
                startPoint = checkpPoint;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. Delete all this code and use an `ItemsControl` and a proper ViewModel for this.

Comment: @highcore, Thanks for that,but how does it helps me achieving multiselection using shift key, would you be able to give me an example?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. A `CheckBox` does not have anything to do with any other CheckBox by default. Therefore you will get multi selection without pressing shift or any other key.

Comment: Using shift key multiselection refers to " holding shift key select begin checkbox and end checkbox, on this action selection of checkbox in between two positions.

Comment: I have updated my question, Found solution using shift keydown and finding the start and end mouse position,select the checkbox within the 2 points/rect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, and for viewers refer [Ashley Davis post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/148503/Simple-Drag-Selection-in-WPF)

The credit goes to Ashley Davis.

Comment: Using this solution, there is an issue if your controls are under scrollviewer, needs to rewrite some bits of code.